# Opening IOS application via link in browser

Tags: ios, browser

For my web application i use: location.href = "market://launch?id=" + incoming_obj; to open an android app or go to android store.
Is there also kind of an action like this for IOS?
If i use the following: location.href = "https://apps.apple.com/nl/app/ns/id" + incoming_obj; than it just opens the Apple store where you can click open on the app.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass the incoming object to the app in a way that the passed data would be accessible to your code upon fresh install, you should implement Universal Deep Linking.

Some developers prefer to use 3rd party services such as Branch.io in order to manage this, because Universal Deep Linking requires some configuration on the server side, and it sometimes easier to delegate this to a 3rd party.

See https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/

Comment: I dont have to pass any object to an app. I just want to open apps direclty like Uber, Train apps and other transport apps.